# Where to puts my project on linux (ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory, filesystems

### Short Question

**Where to put my projects on linux filesystem?**

### Long Question

I have some project (e.g. rust projects).
Where should I put them?
To the documents folder, or to the /usr/src/local/, or should I create folder for it on the root?
I am gonna work on them, but not publish them.
Some of them maybe go to GitHub in future.
I dont gonna using their products (runnable).

### Me

I am new to linux.
I am using ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
And sorry for my english.

Comment: It's common to put non-OS programs in /usr/local.  /usr/local/bin for the program, /usr/local/lib for libraries, etc.